# DirectAdmin + Manual install MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, directadmin

I am currently running CentOS 7 on a VPS managed by DirectAdmin 1.51.3 using Custombuild with MySQL 5.6.x.

For a certain application I need the MySQL 5.7.x JSON features. DirectAdmin currently offers no way to build using anything above MySQL 5.6.

How can I manually upgrade MySQL? Or is there a workaround to use Custombuild with 5.7 after all?

Comment: a quick google search shows that the later versions directadmin does support mysql 5.7.x. If you have ssh and root access on your VPS, you can manually update mysql through centos' package manager

Comment: Interesting, I updated DirectAdmin to the latest version and still, `build versions` only displays 5.6.x as the latest version for MySQL.

I can't find it either by Googling. Do you have a link to a page that confirms this?

I do have SSH root access, so that is a good backup. I just don't know how to "overwrite" the current DirectAdmin MySQL installation with a new one.

Comment: checking the actual list of services they support does only show until mysql 5.6 but checking their changelogs show that they do support 5.7 like in this bugfix in 1.52 https://www.directadmin.com/features.php?id=1840

Comment: From the looks of it, indeed, MySQL 5.7 seems to be supported. However, running 
`./build set mysql 5.7` 
returns:
`5.7 is not a valid setting for mysql option.`. 
I guess I'll have to do it manually for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this discussion [thread](http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=51166), you should be able to upgrade your mysql installation manually through rpms or the package manager.

```
$ wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.n‌​oarch.rpm
$ sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm
$ sudo yum install mysql-community-{server,client,common,libs}-*
$ sudo service mysqld restart
```

Though before taking the plunge with upgrading your database, be sure to backup your database first to ensure that even if data gets corrupted during the upgrade process or it simply just doesnt work out as intended, your data is safe and you can always restore your data from the backup or safely rollback

Comment: This worked. For future reference, the official yum repository contains 5.6.x, no 5.7.x releases. First install the MySQL yum repository:
`wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm`
`yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm`
and then install:
`sudo yum install mysql-community-{server,client,common,libs}-*`
`sudo service mysqld restart`